# Python TypeError float is not callable while using scipy.optimize.flove

Tags: python, scipy

Here is a short program which is giving me an error about Python TypeError float is not callable, I'm having a difficult time understanding:

```
def ajust_or(var,*param):
    ind_new,or3,or2,or1,high_freq_3,med_freq_2,low_freq_1 = param

    g_low = var[0]
    g_med = var[1]
    g_high = var[2]
    print type(g_low)
    return[
       g_low*low_freq_1 + g_med*med_freq_2 + g_high*high_freq_3 - ind_new   
       (g_med/(1-g_med))/(g_low/(1-g_low)) - or2 
       (g_high/(1-g_high))/(g_low/(1-g_low)) - or3 
    ]
```

Comment: can you post full code, include the call of `fsolve`.

Comment: Show the entire traceback.

Comment: Your function's signature makes no sense. You have a `*param` argument that you immediately unpack into 7 positional arguments; why isn't the function defined as `ajust_or(var,ind_new,or3,or2,or1,high_freq_3,med_freq_2,low_freq_1)`?

Comment: missing operators: lines end with a float variable and next lines continue with a bracket and no operator in between, which makes a call to a float, and `float is not callable`, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return[
   g_low*low_freq_1 + g_med*med_freq_2 + g_high*high_freq_3 - ind_new   
   (g_med/(1-g_med))/(g_low/(1-g_low)) - or2 
   (g_high/(1-g_high))/(g_low/(1-g_low)) - or3 
]
```

You forgot your commas. This code is trying to call `ind_new` with the argument `g_med/(1-g_med)` and call `or2` with the argument `g_high/(1-g_high)`.